# Centos Webserver Management

Tags: linux, webserver, centos, centos6

I have just setup 5 centos 6 servers. I want to turn then all into webservers but I want one server to be able to control all the servers and install websites on them. How do I do this? Is there some software I could use that is preflably free.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend puppet configuration management system to automate your installation/configuration process. it is open source. it has one centralized server used to store/distribute configuration/updates across your network infrastructure.

reference
http://puppetlabs.com/

Hope it helps